# Listing files in the root of my usb drive

Tags: windows

How would I get a list of directories of the root of my f drive without listing the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir /ad f:\`

Comment: ty===================

Comment: @Dan: For more info, see `dir /?` or `help dir`.